# Printing definitions properly

Tags: printing, save, general-utilities

GeneralUtilities's definition printing functions are very useful, I find them much better than Save and friends because they format the code properly. However, `PrintNonhyperlinkedDefinitions[]` has two issues:

1. *code generated still contains hyperlinks*
2. *dependencies aren't printed*

For example:

```
h[x_] := x
g[x_] := h[x]
f[x_] := g[x]

GeneralUtilities`PrintNonhyperlinkedDefinitions[f]
```

[image]

In the above, `f` is really a hyperlink and `h` and `g`'s definitions are missing. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: The output on my computer Mathematica 10.3.1 is `f[x_]:=g[x];` and `f` is not hyperlinked but has a tooltip.

Comment: I just meant it's not plaintext code.